# how to decrypt hidden text under numbers?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

got a question as follows -
how to decrypt below in to letters knowing that crypting language is 469 and it base ofcourse on mathematic.

46781! 9063376290 3222011 677 80322429 67538 14805394, 6880326 677 63378129 337011 72683 149630 4378! 453 639 578300 986372 2953639! I know it’s rather short, but still, this poem I like best."

im strugling to find code for that for a long time.
or where should i look for any possible methods to decript this ?

Comment: Is this for some sort of online challenge or for school? "crypting language is 469", what does that even mean?

Comment: online riddle. regarding 469 thats whats its said to be language thats used to code this message and there is way more of them thats the one thats splited in to words look like number other ones are just lines of 80+ digits strings